# Time compleity of dynamic arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, dynamic

When we consider dynamic arrays in Java or python (list), the average time complexity is **O(1)** for appending an element and worst time complexity is **O(n)**. Say we are trying to append 'm' elements, then every time we reach the maximum array size, we double the size and then copy all the elements which takes 2m+m = 3m and hence, O(m) to append m elements (amortized).

**Question** : Consider C language, where, to have a dynamic array we have a pointer pointing to start of array of size m. Now if the pointer reaches the maximum size then we use realloc() to increase the size and then point the pointer to the first location of newly created array with realloc(). Hence, we are not copying all the elements over again but instead we are just moving the pointer to point to the newly created array with increased size. So how would this affect the time complexity?

C example code taken from : [here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation)

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int *ptr, i , n1, n2;
printf("Enter size: ");
scanf("%d", &n1);

ptr = (int*) malloc(n1 * sizeof(int));

printf("Addresses of previously allocated memory: ");
for(i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
     printf("%u\n",ptr + i);

printf("\nEnter the new size: ");
scanf("%d", &n2);

// rellocating the memory
ptr = realloc(ptr, n2 * sizeof(int));

printf("Addresses of newly allocated memory: ");
for(i = 0; i < n2; ++i)
     printf("%u\n", ptr + i);

free(ptr);

return 0;
```

}

```
Enter size: 2
Addresses of previously allocated memory:26855472
26855476
Enter the new size: 4
Addresses of newly allocated memory:26855472
26855476
26855480
26855484
```

Comment: How do you think `realloc` provides a “newly created array” that has the same contents as the old one?

Comment: The point of `realloc` is that it implicitly allocates a new buffer of requested size, copies whichever is least between the old size and the new size, frees the original buffer, and then returns the pointer to the new buffer. The result of a simple `realloc` implementation is effectively a `malloc()` + `memcpy()` + `free()`. An actual implementation *could* check to see if simply extending the existing allocation is possible, but there's no reason to assume that a copy won't happen.

Comment: You should print pointers with `%p` and cast to `void*`. Using an integer format specifier or any other pointer type causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question with a sample code. You can see that even after realloc the memeory address where values of older array were stored are still same in new array. So I don't understand how do you say that relloc copies the array internally because if that was the case the address of the 'copied' elements must be different right ?

Comment: First of all, `realloc` will check if there is more memory available right after the current block. If yes, then just take it and that's it. If not, then a new block must be found and the whole buffer will be copied.

Comment: @Gerhardh if that's the case it makes sense. let me read up more on realloc(). Thanks!

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal, although `realloc()` *might* be able to reallocate in-place some of the time, you cannot rely on it to do so, nor easily predict when it will do.  For an asymptotic complexity analysis, then, you must assume that it allocates a separate block and performs appropriate copying, exactly as you describe for Java and Python.

Comment: As I said (adding here in case someone don't sees my answer post), do not realloc a pointer straight to itself (```myptr = realloc(myptr, size)```). Reallocation can fail, and in that case realloc will return null, but not free the pointer passed as a parameter. If you override the pointer directly with the return value, you may set to null a valid pointer and create a memory leak.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Re “First of all, `realloc` will check if there is more memory available right after the current block”: That is not part of the `realloc` specification and should not be relied upon without specification documentation for an implementation. There are a variety of memory allocation schemes. If a study in one context shows many allocations of, say, 16 bytes or fewer, `malloc` and `realloc` might be implemented using a bitmap to manage a large pool of fixed 16-byte sized blocks and some other scheme for other sizes…

Comment: … In such an implementation, a 16-byte block could not be expanded to a larger size even if the blocks after it were available, because the bitmap provides no way to mark the following blocks as related. It would have to be freed and replaced by a block from the general allocation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you are right in a language lawyer perspective. You cannot rely on it. But if you allocate 8 out of those 16 bytes in such a fixed size pool, you can still apply that mechanism to the other 8 bytes when enlarging to 16 bytes and use same block of 16 bytes. I would really be disappointed if any implementation would give me part of a block and then not try to reuse the other part of that same block at least.

Comment: "then copy all the elements which takes 2m+m ..." --> An underlying OS can remap blocks of data effective taking O(1) rather than copying.  Even copying/clearing can be done in idle time effectively making time cost for the code zero.  Allocated memory, but not used, can get truly allocated later.   There are many possibilities to `*alloc()` implementation and the data set in trying to determine its performance.  Simply use reasonable coding.

Comment: "...hence, O(m) to append m elements (amortized)." To me statement is wrong. You perform an operation which is O(1) m times but that doesn't make it O(m) as there is no relation to the array size.

Comment: @EricPostpischil from what I understand from your comment, if, say, a block of 16 bytes is full, then I cannot expand this block because there is bit mapping of blocks of size 16 bytes only. So what happens when I use the memory of one complete block ( size 16 bytes) ?  Do I go back and re-create blocks of larger size and re map it and then copy al the elements from previous block of size 16b to this new one of size 32b?

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal: No, we were discussing internal implementation details. They are not relevant to how you use `realloc`, except to emphasize that you cannot rely on specific behaviors other than those documented for it. Per the documentation, when you call `realloc`, it will either give you a new pointer (which might be equal to the old pointer), and the data at the previous location will have been copied by `realloc` to the new location (if different) up to the shorter of the new and old sizes or it give you a null pointer, and the data will still be at the previous location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure of what you do, but I assume that somewhere in your code you want to use

```
tmp = realloc(my_array, new size);
if(!tmp) {
//errors
}
my_array = tmp
```

instead of

```
new_array = malloc(array new size);
if(!new_array){
//errors
}
copy_array(my_array, new_array); //by a for loop or stuff like that
free(my_array);
my_array = new_array;
```

Actually both are quite the same, and realloc is simply a more expressive version of doing it a malloc and then copy (also potentially faster and more optimized).

realloc works like this :

- If it is possible, increase/decrease the size of the zone currently allocated for the pointer and return it.
- If not (there is already allocated space in front of the zone we want to extend), find some other place in RAM and alloc there, then copy old zone in the new one and return pointer to the new zone.
- If no place is found, return null

Because of this, the overall complexity will not change if you still use a trick as doubling size when reallocating. It will be amortized constant, worst case linear.
If you don't use a trick, e.g if you realloc at each insertion, the complexity will be worst case linear, average linear, best case constant.

EDIT :
realloc is not meant to reduce complexity, but it can increase performances, as it will not copy elements if possible. Please note that it may vary a bit from a compiler to another, and from the source you choose.
Another good reason to use realloc is that is much clearer about what you intent to do.
Finally, don't realloc a pointer to itself like `myptr = realloc(myptr)`, because a realloc can still fail and return null, and would not free myptr before overriding it, which can lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful !

Comment: Re "*realloc is not meant to reduce complexity*", Indeed. Complexity is not a measure of performance; it's a measure of how something scales.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ouups my bad, fixing that right now, thanks !